# Bad configuration PHP - AIR

Tags: php, air

AIR CODE:

```
for(var j:int=0;j&quote ContenedorListaArchivos.numChildren;j++) 
{ 

    var M:MovieClip = MovieClip(ContenedorListaArchivos.getChildAt(j)); 

    if(M.UploadedFile.Estado==1) 
    { 
    var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(M.FullPath);                     
    file.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,M.ProgresoUpload);
    file.addEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA,M.CompleteUpload);  ‌​ 
    file.upload(new URLRequest(_phpscript+"?Opcion=UploadFile&destination="+_destination));
    } 
}
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php

tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['Filedata']['size'];

$dir = ($_GET['destination']) ? $_GET['destination'] : 'images';

if (!file_exists($dir)) mkdir($dir, 0777);

$isMove =move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $dir .'/'. $fileName);

if($isMove)
echo "OK";
else
echo "NO";

?>
```

when I upload one file the PHP return OK. 
But, when upload multiple files, only the first copy is "OK", the other returning "NO".

Why? What is wrong in the code?
What should I change in the file PHP.ini?

Thank you, best regards.

Comment: how you tried to upload multiple file? the code you posted is for uploading single file...

Comment: loop your code to upload multiple files

Comment: The upload is from AIR.

Comment: post this code in your question not in comment.

Comment: Yes, is a loop from AIR as3.

Answer (score 0):

you loose the homeworks ? **Uploading multiple files**

```
<form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Send these files:<br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
</form>
```

When the above form is submitted, the arrays $_FILES['userfile'], $_FILES['userfile']['name'], and $_FILES['userfile']['size'] will be initialized (as well as in $HTTP_POST_FILES for PHP versions prior to 4.1.0). When register_globals is on, globals for uploaded files are also initialized. Each of these will be a numerically indexed array of the appropriate values for the submitted files.

For instance, assume that the filenames /home/test/review.html and /home/test/xwp.out are submitted. In this case, $_FILES['userfile']['name'][0] would contain the value review.html, and $_FILES['userfile']['name'][1] would contain the value xwp.out. Similarly, $_FILES['userfile']['size'][0] would contain review.html's file size, and so forth.

$_FILES['userfile']['name'][0], $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][0], $_FILES['userfile']['size'][0], and $_FILES['userfile']['type'][0] are also set.

***if you are a starter***

```
<?php

function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {

$file_ary = array();
$file_count = count($file_post['name']);
$file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
    foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
        $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
    }
 }

 return $file_ary;
}



    if ($_FILES['upload']) {
        $file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['userfile']);

        foreach ($file_ary as $file) {
            print 'File Name: ' . $file['name'];
            print 'File Type: ' . $file['type'];
            print 'File Size: ' . $file['size'];
        }
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: This answer is for `html` and `PHP`, but OP is using `Flex`.

Comment: The PHP config have this variables: memory_limit 128M; post_max_size 100M; upload_max_filesize 100M; max_file_uploads 20;

Comment: When I wait two minutes and try again, always upload the first file correctly, others not.

Comment: @Yogesh Suthar : OP! edited that  , when i answered it  there was only php codes ,still now the tag is PHP